# How can I find a website's login form URL variables?

Tags: html, url, authentication

I am trying to make a code that will automatically login into a webpage for you, but I am having trouble finding the url variables for the submission.

How can I find the url variables to submit the login?

i.e.

```
https://login.fidelity.com/ftgw/Fas/Fidelity/RtlCust/Login/Init
```

When I submit my username and password on the site, it passes it through to

```
https://login.fidelity.com/ftgw/Fas/Fidelity/RtlCust/Login/Response
```

The username `<input>` has `id="userId"`, and the password `<input>` has `id="password"`, and this is all under a `<form>` which has `method="POST"`

How can I find all variables that I need to submit?

Comment: Do you want to pass values like username and pass word to another page? *Clarify...*

Comment: Most login forms (the sensible ones) send data via a POST request meaning the fields won't show up in the URL. You could scrape the login page for a form and find all the `<input>`s in that, though

Comment: It's a really bad idea to pass a user's username and password in the URL unless you want to get hacked and/or sued. :)

Comment: You're looking for name="Username" or something like that, not id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL variables aren't always in the URL.

Most Login forms use a method of transferring that data called "POST".

In which the URL data cannot be seen by the user.

You can try using http://www.wireshark.org/ or http://www.charlesproxy.com/ to view the data sent and received by your web browser.

To find the name of the URL parameters (such as ?username=....&pas=...).
You can look into the HTML of the page. Look for something like so:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="User Types Username Here">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Or just Firebug or Web Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Can use Chrome (Ctrl + Shift + J) Network tools. Click "Preserve Log" to ensure you capture payload before page refreshes.